# PyRun_String stop sending result to stdout after any error

Tags: c++, python, c

I'm writing a Python terminal GUI in C++. I'm using the following code to run a user-typed Python command-line:

```
void RunTerminalCommand (char * line) 
{

    PyObject *py_main, *py_dict;
    py_main = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
    py_dict = PyModule_GetDict(py_main);
    PyObject * PyRes = PyRun_String(line, Py_single_input, py_dict, py_dict);

    return 0;
}
```

It works very well, with the command line being executed and the result being printed on the output window via stdout. But whenever the Python command line leads to a Python error, it stops working: My stdout doesn't receive any data

Notes:

- PyRes always returns NULL, even before the error line is injected
- I don't know if I should call PyImport_AddModule every time. But it seems to work this way.
- If I use **PyRun_SimpleString(line)** insted of **PyRun_String(line, Py_single_input, py_dict, py_dict)**, it always work, and I still get the Error messages via stdout/stderr. But this call doesn't send the result of command line evaluatiosn to stdout, so I don't want to use it. For example, the command line "2+2" will print "4" on stdout when I use PyRun_String, but not when I use PyRun_SimpleString.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've gone through a similar problem, and solved it by adding a "\n" (Carriage-return) using Py_Run_SimpleString right after the user command line, as in the example:

```
PyRun_String(line, Py_single_input, py_dict, py_dict);
PyRun_SimpleString("\n");
```

It doesn't work if you add the "\n" at the end of PyRun_String. It needs to be a separated call to PyRun_SimpleString

Answer (score 0):

First there's this in the documentation of `PyImport_AddModule`:

> First check the modules dictionary if there’s one there, and if not, create a new one and insert it in the modules dictionary. Return NULL with an exception set on failure.

You don't check that the module is already in the dictionary first.

In the documentation for `PyRun_String` there's this:

> Returns the result of executing the code as a Python object, or NULL if an exception was raised.

You don't ever check if it succeeded or not.

There's a few other things that are missing from your code.  I think the main point is that you go and **read the documentation** and make sure you understand what it says and write the code required to check for error conditions, etc...

Comment: I didn't post the full code, so this may had lead you to think that I didn't check the return of PyRun_String. I did, and it always return NULL, as I've said in the question. But sorry for not posting the full code. I tryied to simplify and narrow down the problem to these fewer lines of code.